# GLFW window creation options affecting the HarfBuzz

Tags: opengl, glsl, glfw, freetype, harfbuzz

I am using HarfBuzz along with freetype to render regional language hindi.

If I write these three optins for window creation than  the font does not render and  I only see the blank screen.

```
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
```

Without these three options the font renders correctly.

I am curious to know what difference these options make in window creation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because you create a core profile [OpenGL Context](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Context#Context_types) (`GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE`).
In compare to a compatibility profile context (`GLFW_OPENGL_COMPAT_PROFILE`), which is default, [Legacy OpenGL](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Legacy_OpenGL) OpenGL instructions are not valid and cause OpenGL errors.

The main difference is, that you can't use [`glBegin`/`glEnd`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glBegin.xml) sequences, fixed function attributes (e.g. [`glVertexPointer`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glVertexPointer.xml)) respectively client-side capability or the current matrix stack.
If you want to draw geometry, then you've to create [Vertex Array Objects](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Vertex_Array_Object) and to use [Shader](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Shader) programs.

The complete differences can be seen in the [OpenGL 3.3 Compatibility Profile specification](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec33.compatibility.pdf) or for the most recent OpenGL version [OpenGL 4.6 API Compatibility Profile Specification](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec46.compatibility.pdf),  where the functionality that is only in the compatibility profile specification and not in the core specification is typeset in orange.